# Asking for UIHostingController's view returns nil

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a share button which should share a meme (image + top text + bottom text). Here is the code concerning this button :

```
Button(
                        action: {
                            items.removeAll()
                            items.append(createImage(from: UIHostingController(rootView: Meme(image: image, topText: topText, bottomText: bottomText)).view))
                            showingSharePage = true
                        }
                    ) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
```

As you can see, I append the item to be shared to items. What I share is a UIImage generated with a UIView with this function :

```
func createImage(from view: UIView) -> UIImage {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), true, 1)
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let generatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return generatedImage!
}
```

But when I run on the simulator or on the device itself, I get this error : "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in the line "view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)" in createImage function.

Here is my meme struct :

```
struct Meme: View {
    @State var image: Image?
    @State var topText: String
    @State var bottomText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        image!
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
            .overlay(
                TextField("TOP", text: $topText)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(Font.custom("HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 30))
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.75)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.vertical, 50.0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        topText = ""
                    },
                alignment: .top
            )
            .overlay(
                TextField("BOTTOM", text: $bottomText)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(Font.custom("HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 30))
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.75)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.vertical, 50.0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        bottomText = ""
                    },
                alignment: .bottom
            )
    }
}
```

Do you know why it is returning nil ?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image ?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough The problem is in these lines

```
UIHostingController(rootView: Meme(image: image, topText: topText, bottomText: bottomText)).view)
```

and

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), true, 1)
```

Much to my surprise the view returned by UIHostingViewController has an initial frame of CGRect.zero

So you're actually telling the context to have a point size of zero which apparently it just silently fails for. You can double check this by printing the size in your createImage: function

```
print(view.frame)
```

or

```
print(view.frame.size)
```

I'm pretty sure that's the problem though.